# Error Passing param to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to pass a parameter to a javascript function, so thi is my code:

```
deleteFormatter${id_sec_field} = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    url = '${submitUrl}/' + cellvalue;
    return '<div><a href="#" onclick="deleteHandler('+url+');"><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span></a></div>';
}
```

But in this way I can't pass `url` as variable because I get this eror:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'utente'
```

And if I check my generated code I obtain this:

```
<div><a href="#" onclick="deleteHandler(/myapp/user/2);"><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span></a></div>
```

Comment: Wrap the parameter in quotes: `onclick="deleteHandler(\''+url+'\');"`

Comment: @Tushar Thank you!! if you want answer I delete my owned answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest by comment, I solved in this way:

```
onclick="deleteHandler(\''+url+'\');"
```